# C# forms daily mail sending with time, days check with Windows Service

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, windows-services

I read about sending mails daily when it's check time comes and I made this code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

        if (Header.isSendMailNow() == true) //checks if the mail sending time comes
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = Header.OverTimeRequests("1");//Returns datatable with overdated requests from sql database
                Header.respondOverTimedRequest(dt, "Customer Message", 1);//send "Customer Message" to the people in dt
                dt = Header.OverTimeRequests("2");
                Header.respondOverTimedRequest(dt, "Customer Message", 1);
                Header.respondOverTimedRequest(dt, "Employee Message", 2);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will run perfectly while the program runs; but I want it to run even program closed. I got confused while reading windows server usage tutorials, so can someone guide me how to do it or at least better and basic link will be ok, too.

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried the steps in the link; but got an exception:               An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot open database "teknik_test" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.                        I jusy wrote whole if statement in the code that I gave into the OnStart method. Program crash in conn.Open();

Comment: nevermind, its just because of using windows authentication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TopShelf` for that which will make your c# application work whenever you start the service and stops whenever you stop the service.

go through below link more details :-

http://topshelf-project.com/

http://jaysonrowe.blogspot.in/2012/09/using-topshelf-to-create-windows-service.html

Comment: it can be good, but I want only mailing part work not whole project if I understand it right.